# which JDK version required for javapns 2.1?

Tags: java, iphone, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-5

I want to send push notification to iphone for available new version of the application so I am using  `<a href='http://code.google.com/p/javapns/'>javapns 2.1</a>`.

I  tried this on my local computer and it is working fine but on the server it throws the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

On the server and local machine the tomcat and the JDK is different so which version required for <`a href='http://code.google.com/p/javapns/'>javapns 2.1</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPNS requires Java 1.5.  Since JavaPNS does not use reflection, the InvocationTargetException most likely comes from somewhere else.  Could you post the entire stack trace, as well as the code that throws that exception?